# Redis build fails on new RaspberryPi 4 using Raspbian Buster

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, debian-buster

I am getting a linker error when trying to build `redis-stable` (should be 5.0.5) on `raspbian buster` running on the latest `Raspberry Pi 4`

`make` goes through the motions and then fails with the following

```sh
    LINK redis-server
/usr/bin/ld: networking.o: in function `createClient':
/home/pi/redis-stable/src/networking.c:109: undefined reference to `__atomic_fetch_add_8'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [Makefile:219: redis-server] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/redis-stable/src'
make: *** [Makefile:6: all] Error 2
```

Am I missing a setting somewhere?

Comment: Try adding `-latomic` to your compiler flags.

Comment: same issue here. did you find a solution? cheers

Comment: @JVLobo I added -latomic command to the Makefile in the src folder and that got the build going, but tests never passed. They look like timeout issues... currently trying to setup a more robust storage medium than my cheap SD card before I run the tests again.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get all the tests to run successfully by adding the compiler flag `-latomic` only to the `redis-server`

```
# redis-server                                                                                                                                                
$(REDIS_SERVER_NAME): $(REDIS_SERVER_OBJ)                                                                                                                     
        $(REDIS_LD) -o $@ $^ ../deps/hiredis/libhiredis.a ../deps/lua/src/liblua.a $(FINAL_LIBS) -latomic
```

**EDIT: This is with Redis 5.0.5**

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run by adding the compiler flag -latomic only to the haproxy

[error]

```
/home/pi/CQ/LB/haproxy-1.8.21/src/proto_http.c:12152: undefined reference to `__atomic_fetch_add_8'
..........................................
..........................................
/usr/bin/ld: src/proto_http.o:/home/pi/CQ/LB/haproxy-1.8.21/src/proto_http.c:4200: more undefined references to `__atomic_fetch_add_8' follow
/usr/bin/ld: src/time.o: in function `tv_update_date':
/home/pi/CQ/LB/haproxy-1.8.21/src/time.c:229: undefined reference to `__atomic_compare_exchange_8'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:914: haproxy] error 1
```

[adding]

```
913 haproxy: $(OPTIONS_OBJS) $(EBTREE_OBJS) $(OBJS)
914          $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDOPTS) -latomic
```